# Как разрезать объект (по знаку) и преобразовать в массив?

Tags: c#, объекты

Если ставить эту задачу для строки (разрезать по знаку и преобразовать в массив), то решение такое:

```
//ввести имя файла
Console.WriteLine("Введите имя файла");
string fileName = Console.ReadLine();

//прочитать файл
string filePath = @"D:\" + fileName + ".txt";
string stringArray = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

//разрезать строку и преобразовать в массив
string[] stringArraySplit = stringArray.Split(' ');
```

***Но если файл загружается, как ниже, непонятно, как решить задачу. Подскажите, плиз, куда рыть.***

```
//создаем файловый поток
FileStream file = new FileStream("d:\\new.txt", FileMode.Open);

// создаем «потоковый читатель» и связываем его с файловым потоком 
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете использовать для этих целей **StreamReader**.

```
  // Создаем "читатель".
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("путь к файлу");

  // Читаем весь файл.
  string text = sr.ReadToEnd();

  // Режем по символу.
  var result = text.Split(' ');
```